# Remove item- hashtable

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I am working on a project to put in hashtable (resolving conflicts with seperate chaining )IDs of images formed from 28*28 array stored in only 1D array.
Hashatable is array of pointers to Node which contains the image and its ID. The get function returns ID and it works perfectly except if I remove a specific image and then try to get it... an infinite loop is generated and the old ID is still there !!

```
int get(image img)
{
    int i = hashCode(img);
    if(hashtable[i])
    {
        Node* temp = hashtable[i];
        //prints the ID which is suposed to be deleted
        printf("%d\n\n",temp->info.key);
        int found ;
        while(temp)
        {` `//infinite loop
            found = 1;
            for(i =0; i<sizeOfFile; i++)
            {
                if(temp->info.data.img_arr[i]!=img.img_arr[i])
                {
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }` 

            if(found==0)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else
            {
                return temp->info.key;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

return function

```
  int removi(image img)
{    Node*prev=NULL;
    int i = hashCode(img);
    if(hashtable[i])
    {  Node* temp = hashtable[i];
        int found ;
        while(temp)
        {    found = 1;
            for(i =0; i<sizeOfFile; i++)
            {    if(temp->info.data.img_arr[i]!=img.img_arr[i])
                {  found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found==0)
            {   prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }else{
                int value = temp->info.key;
                if(prev){
                    prev->next = temp->next;
                }else{
                    hashtable[i]=temp->next;
                    //prints correctly the ID of next Node
                    printf("%d in remove\n",hashtable[i]->info.key);
                }
                free(temp);
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You can greatly simplify your logic by using for() loops, early returns, and not using the`found` indicator variable. And, a pointer-to-pointer would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `removi` function you are reusing your index value `i`.  The value `int i = hashCode(img);` is modified later by your for loop: `for(i =0; i<sizeOfFile; i++);`

Therefore your line to remove the element (when it's the head element in your list): `hashtable[i]=temp->next;` 
doesn't actually remove it -- instead it botches some other list or invokes undefined behavior if `i` is outside the bounds.